# How to join an array with an additional element in `bash`?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Suppose I have a bash for-loop

```
for name in *; do
    printf $(some stats about $name)
done
```

Now I would like to also print the same `stats` about the current folder itself, in other word, something like

```
for name in (* and .); do   # NOT VALID BASH COMMAND
    printf $(some stats about $name)
done
```

My question is what should I do for the "pseudo-command" `(* and .)`?

I know I can simply do `printf $(some stats about .)` after the for-loop, but I would like to know whether there is a more generic way of doing so. (Just assume `$(some stats about $name)` is long and I would like to avoid defining another function if possible). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply

```
for name in * . ; do
    printf $(some stats about $name)
done
```

to add an element to the list over which the `for` loop runs.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect something so simple.. Thanks!